# Why doesn't this UIImageView Show up?

Tags: objective-c, ios, quartz-graphics

If I set this UIImageView as an IBOutlet it works fine and shows up in the sim. But programmatically it isn't working. I think I am missing a step or forgetting a line of code.

It is declared as

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView  *circleView;
```

and the implementation

```
self.circleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,   self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.circleView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:circleView];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to initialize your `UIImageView` that's why it's not working ...

```
self.circleView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
self.circleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,   self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.circleView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:circleView];
```